# omission of normal verbs

Tags: grammar

> "Through the thick wood, that gave him way, and past the thorns that drew
>
> Their sharpest points another way, the King's son presses through.
>
> He reached the guard, the court, the hall,—and there, where'er he stept,
>
> He saw the sentinels, and grooms, and courtiers as they slept.
>
> **Ladies in act to smile, and pages in attendance wait;**"

This is from Walter Crane's Sleeping Beauty (http://www.gutenberg.org/files/23521/23521-h/23521-h.htm). I wonder what verbs would have been in the bolded last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

This line does have a rather twisted syntax, in order to make it rhyme. However, there are no verbs missing. Dropping the intervening prepositional phrases, you get

> ladies and pages wait.

Paraphrased, this line means

> ladies (caught in the act of starting to smile) wait to smile, and pages wait to attend (on their masters).

Since pages *wait* on their masters, and these ladies might be *ladies-in-waiting*, there is a subtle play on words here.

Comment: _Ladies caught in the act of smiling wait to smile_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I said that wrong, didn't I?

Comment: Your explanation makes sense now (and I hadn't seen this possible exposition), but are you sure that's the sense of the original? I'm guessing at '[There are] ladies caught in the [very] act of smiling; and pages in attendance wait.' The original mixes present historic and past simple worryingly, at any rate. I'll try to check other verses.

Comment: '[W]as never beauty such as this ...' deletes the existential 'there' a little later. I suspect verb deletion here.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any omitted verbs.  The use of "in act" is a little strange, but otherwise, the sentence is readable: "Ladies smile, pages wait".

Comment: I don't see how _smile_ can be a finite verb, but _wait_ certainly is.